# All of my executables are trying to open via 7zip. How can I put them back to normal?

Tags: laptop, 7-zip, file-association

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you associate the .exe file extension with a program in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/354771/how-do-you-associate-the-exe-file-extension-with-a-program-in-windows)

I recently booted my computer and all of the executable files have turned into 7zip icons.  A hoard of error messages popped up upon startup stating that 7zip could not open the files.

2 questions:

1. How do I restore this problem so I can open my programs and my computer will boot normally?
2. What caused this and how do I prevent this from coming back?

Comment: This is not a virus the same thing happened to me after I tried to open a windows media player INK file with 7-zip. So maybe your tried to open something that your shouldn't have or something went wrong with computer.

Comment: Try this answer: http://superuser.com/q/354788/101850

Answer (score 2):

Certainly, to me this sounds like a virus. I would immediately run a complete scan using EVERY anti virus I have AFTER disconnecting from the internet.

I use Malwarebytes and Microsoft Security Essentials.

Good luck.

Comment: Agreed, this is definitely not something that happens randomly, it is almost certainly malicious.