# How do you associate the .exe file extension with a program in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-association

A few years ago I saw somebody play a prank on somebody by associating the `.exe` file extension with Internet Explorer. This made Internet Explorer open up every time the person wanted to start a program.

Unfortunately, I forgot how this was done. I tried to use the `Default Programs > Set Associations` Control Panel tool, but it didn't list `.exe`.

How could one set this file association, and, perhaps more importantly, how could one unset it?

Comment: it's on a batch virus google search

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When doing "pranks" like that, it is not enough to just follow a step-by-step tutorial or a batch script; it's best to know something about how the actual data is stored – it becomes easier to recover later.

All file associations are kept in Registry, which can be edited using *regedit* or *reg*. The shell looks for them under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, which is a merged view of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` (system-wide) and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` (user-local).

- [ `HKEY_CLASS_ROOT` ]

  - [ `.txt` ]

    - *(default)* = " `txtfile` " – pointer to another key under HKCR
  - [ `txtfile` ]

    - *(default)* = " `Text Document` " – textual description as displayed in Explorer
    - [ `shell` ] – the actions to use for double-click and context-menu

      - *(default)* = *(not set)* – the action to use on double-click; defaults to "`open`"
      - [ `open` ]

        - *(default)* = *(not set)* – label displayed in context menu; defaults to "`Open`"
        - [ `command` ]

          - *(default)* = " `%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1` "

For most extensions, the `HKCR\.extn\(Default)` value points to a *file type* key under the same HKCR; for example, `.exe` points to `HKCR\exefile`.

(In rare cases, though, all information is under the extension's key directly, with `HKCR\.extn\(Default)` containing the description. These seem to be *very* rare, though – maybe a leftover of Windows 9x or 3.x...)

**Make backups. `reg save HKLM\Software\Classes hklm-classes.hiv`** Also, remember that the Command Prompt does not care about extensions; if you try to run an executable program, it will always run no matter how it is named, or what its extension is associated with.

Comment: Obviously export the registry before doing any changes like this! :)

Comment: @HaydnWVN: `reg save` takes care of that (and also includes metadata, which `reg export` would skip).

Comment: Ah sorry, replied before your **Make backups** edit was posted! ;)

Comment: Don't forget that viewing the raw registry is somewhat the hard way of doing things here.  Microsoft's bundled command interpreter has `FTYPE` and `ASSOC` commands, and the file type list is also [accessible via dialogue boxes in Windows Explorer directly](http://filext.com./faq/broken_exe_association.php).

Comment: @JdeBP: AFAIK, Windows Vista got rid of the editor in Explorer - now it just selects the default action. (I haven't dug deeper, though; still using XP here.) Also, the graphical `regedit` gives a nice overview.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe]
@="exefile"
"Content Type"="application/x-msdownload"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe\PersistentHandler]
@="{098f2470-bae0-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"
```